# Is there an issue with my usage of the method hidePopover?

Tags: angular, typescript, popover

#### Rapid background

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/popover), `popover` is an attribute to display a popup in the screen:

> The popover global attribute is used to designate an element as a popover element.
>
> Popover elements are hidden via `display: none` until opened via an invoking/control element (i.e. a `<button>` or `<input type="button">` with a `popovertarget` attribute) or a `HTMLElement.showPopover()` call.
>
> When open, popover elements will appear above all other elements in the top layer, and won't be influenced by parent elements' `position` or `overflow` styling.

Still according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidePopover), `hidePopover()` is a method that hide our popover:

> The `hidePopover()` method of the `HTMLElement` interface hides a popover element (i.e. one that has a valid popover attribute) by removing it from the top layer and styling it with `display: none`.

#### My implementation

I have a component `modal-options` that when pressing on a button will call the second component `modal-change-password` who is defined with the `popover` attribute to display the pop-up.

```html
<div class="popover">
  <!-- skipping not relevant part -->

  <div id="pwdDocker" class="rounded">
    <button id="updatePwdBtn" popovertarget="updatePwd"><h3>Update password</h3></button>
    <app-modal-change-password id="updatePwd" popover [currentUser]="currentUser" (closeModalEvent)="closeChangePasswordModal()"></app-modal-change-password>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-options',
  templateUrl: './modal-options.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-options.component.scss'],
})
export class ModalOptionsComponent implements OnInit {

// skipping not relevant part

  closeChangePasswordModal(): void {
    const popoverElement = document.getElementById("updatePwd");
    if(popoverElement){
      popoverElement.hidePopover();
    }
  }
}
```

`modal-change-password` is my popover component, in it we have a `button` that will close the pop-up by emitting an `EventEmitter` to the parent.

```html
<div class="alert-box">
  <!-- skipping not relevant part -->

  <div class="alert-box-action">
    <button (click)="save()">Change password</button>
    <button (click)="onClose()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-change-password',
  templateUrl: './modal-change-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-change-password.component.scss'],
})
export class ModalChangePasswordComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() closeModalEvent = new EventEmitter<void>();
  
//skipping not relevant part
  
  onClose(): void {
    this.closeModalEvent.emit();
  }
}
```

#### My issue

The typescript compiler will raise me an error stating `error TS2339: Property 'hidePopover' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.` which totally lose me because:

1. hidePopover() is a method and not a property
2. The method exists and according to MDN, does exist in `HTMLElement`

I am still learning a lot everyday about Typescript and so I might be looking in the wrong direction, but I have been researching for a good amount of time now and because of the very recent nature of this attribute, I haven't found any answers related to my issue.

Why is it raising me an error at the compilation ? How should I update my code to make it work ?

(note: I tried two differents approaches, first with `@ViewChild()` instead of `getElementById()` and then with `togglePopover()` instead just to see if I got an other result, but ended up with the same error for both tries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hidePopover() is a method and not a property

Method is just a special name for "A property whose value is a function". They are still properties.

> The method exists and according to MDN, does exist in HTMLElement

If you look at the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/popover#browser_compatibility) section of the documentation you will note that:

- No browser supported it before May this year
- Firefox still doesn't support it in production (it is locked behind a feature flag).

`hidePopover` is **bleeding edge** technology.

[TypeScript 5.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeBfGBDCMASAKgLIAyAogDYCmAttWFANwBQCIAdABYCWAJtQAKIAA4gAbtQBOACgCUrIA) does not support it. [TypeScript 5.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeBfGBDCMASAKgLIAyAogDYCmAttWFANwBQCIAdABYCWAJtQAKIAA4gAbtQBOACgCUrIA) does support it.

Upgrade your version of TypeScript (or consider avoiding it until it has matured a bit more).